# Android: Aling top of one view with the center horizontal of another view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three ImageView placed horizontally.one at left one at right one is in middle.I want to align middle view top edge with horizontal center of other to views how to achieve this in android.
please tell me soln for above problem.

Comment: can u post some sort of snap,to understand clearly??

Comment: I want to align middle view top edge with horizontal center of other to views???? what are you saying? can you edit it and tell in easy to understand words.

Comment: 3 views horizontally placed.i need top edge of my middle view must start from horizontal center line of other two views.other two views (i.e. left and right) are of same height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `android:layout_alignBaseline = <left or right imageview's id>` property to the middle ImageView.

Comment: This property isnt available for a LinearLayout, which is the best way to place 3 images equally horizontally, which I presume the OP wants. I imagine this is for some button layout to have the centre one offset nicely

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved using a LinearLayout. He needs a RelayiveLayout to place the middle image lower than the other two.

Comment: android:layout_alignBaseline will align ImageView base with left and right layout i don't need that.insted middle layout should start from horizontal center line of other two layouts.and middle layout height is bigger than other two Imageview